# send input from function to variable?

Tags: python, function, variables

how can i store a and b for each time i repeat the function
send input from function to variable?

```
def myfunc():
    a = input("a: ")
    b = input("b: ")
    print(str(a + b))
    repeat()

def repeat():
    repeat = input("repeat? y/n: ")
    if repeat == "y":
      myfunc()

myfunc()
```

i would like to say repeat myfunc() several times and then when the repeat loop is broken print all of the entries.

sorry if unclear i am new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach here would be to use a loop for this in which you'll take input and ask to repeat the loop and break out of the loop depending on the users input much in the same way you do now:

```py
def myfunc():
  numbers = list()

  while True:
    a = input("a: ")
    b = input("b: ")

    numbers.append(a + b)

    if input("repeat? y/n:") != "y":
      break

  print(numbers)
```

If you are headset on your current recursive solution you can `return` the result rather than simply print it:

```py
def myfunc():
    a = input("a: ")
    b = input("b: ")
    
    return [str(a + b)] + repeat()

def repeat():
    repeat = input("repeat? y/n: ")
    if repeat == "y":
      return myfunc()
    return []

print(myfunc())
```